# How to sync iPod ratings and play counts to Banshee?

Tags: 10.10, banshee, ipod

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, and my iPod is a Touch 2G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly common feature request, but unfortunately, it isn't yet available.  Some progress has been made, but this probably won't happen before Banshee's 2.0 release in April.  To stay up-to-date on the progress of this issue, you can CC yourself to this bug report: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=389550

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that using an iPod in *nix requires putting the device into "manual" mode, in which case syncing ratings and play counts back is not available.

Comment: oh. well, thanks. do you know if is it any chance of fixing that in the future?

Comment: I don't know; hopefully eventually. Rhythymbox, Amarok and gtkpod are the three main applications which "support" iPod, so it may be worth following their releases. I haven't tested any of them with my iPod myself, but from what I've read when I looked into this, they all required that the iPod be in manual mode. I have a Windows partition, so I boot into that to use iTunes and sync.